# Runnable and lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I could create a simple Runnable using lambda, like:

```
Runnable runnable = ()->{
    String message = "This is an hard coded string";
    System.out.println(message);
};
```

The limitation with above code it that it has created an Runnable with default constructor(with no arguments).

In practice, Runnable often take information when creating it,like the following:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String message;

    public MyRunnable(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
 }
```

I would ask how to create lambda for Runnable that could take constructor arguments.

Comment: Does it have to be a `Runnable`? You can use a `Consumer<String>`.

Comment: what is the difference between the two code snippets, they do the same thing, you can even make message final in the first snippet

Comment: @eran, in my case, I would use Runnable in Thread or Executor, looks that Consumer<String> doesn't work for my case.

Comment: @luk2302 Thnak you, You are right, moving `message` outside from the body makes it act as a variable for the lambda(closure), which effectively becomes the instance  variable of the closure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no problem with having parameters from outside

```
private void runableWithParameter(final String message) {
    final Runnable runnable = ()->{
        System.out.println(message);
    };
}
```

Comment: I was wondering this myself today. External variables do seem to work with the lambda method just fine. I would be interested to know how this works under the hood but for anyone else looking into this my assumption is that the state of the calling method/parent method is looked up and saved during the creation of the new anonymous runnable.